# Running queries in my new PostgreSQL production database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I just launched my Rails app that I am building in Cloud9 to Heroku (woohoo!). My default database was sqlite3, so in the deployment process I added PostgreSQL in my gem as such:

```
# Use postgresql as the database in production
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
# Use sqlite3 as the database in development
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

I want to keep my sqlite3 database in development and use PostgreSQL for production. My question is how do I monitor or run queries for the PostgreSQL data in my production Heroku site.

I'm used to running "rails c" then "User.all" in my terminal to see my users. Now if I run that it doesn't show any data from production. How do I see that data? I did some searching and i think I should be using "psql" command. But if I run "psql -l" for example I get:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to run some PostgreSQL queries on Heroku production then type following command in your terminal:

```
heroku pg:psql (or heroku pg:psql -a your-heroku-app-name)
```

Here you will be able to run such queries like `select * from users`. To exit the terminal type `\q`.

You can also invoke Heroku production console with

```
heroku run console (or heroku run console -a your-heroku-app-name)
```

to run such queries like `User.all`.